# Passing variable from vbs to batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to pass a string that is contained in a variable named `sDateFile` into `test.bat` using the following line:

```
WshShell.Run "test.bat sDateFile"
```

And to check whether `test.bat` has received the variable. I get `test.bat` to do the following:

```
echo %1
```

But my output is `sDateFile`, not the string in the variable.
Am I approaching my problem incorrectly? Would there be a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concat your bat file and the value of sDateFile. There is a SPACE after `test.bat`

```
WshShell.Run "test.bat " + chr(34) + sDateFile + chr(34)
```

[Run command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to get it to work. Without having to use chr: WshShell.run "test.bat " + sDateFile 
Most other solutions use & instead of + if i may ask why did it work with + ?

Comment: EDIT: Ok so i understand that the need for concat is to run the batch file with the variable the real problem was the SPACE. Thanks rene! I do feel really silly now. xD